# Clean unused tokens of Apple Push Notification on server-side

Tags: iphone, apple-push-notifications

I have my own server to implement Apple Push Notification. The implementation is:

- my server store APNS tokens of user in a table
- whenever there's a new pushing, it's retrieve tokens from that table, then push.

Pushing is OK. But I have a confused issue: If the user turn off the APNS setting, how does my server know that, so it don't need to push to that token?

Please help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You should check periodically if a token is stil valid. You can use the [Apple APNS feedback service](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CommunicatingWIthAPS/CommunicatingWIthAPS.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH101-SW3).

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your query about comprehensive sample code in PHP for communicating with the APNS Feedback Service, searching on Google for "apns feedback php" returns several pages that explain how to do this... The first few pages that show up in the results actually contain code samples you might find useful, as well as a project that might be what you are looking for (http://code.google.com/p/apns-php/).